# Печать документов и изображений на Perl

Tags: perl, печать

Подскажите как распечатать документ или изображение на Perl? И возможно ли это?

Comment: Скорее всего возможно, если это в принципе возможно на вашей операционной системе. Например под linux смотрите cups.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, возможно.

```
cpan install Net::CUPS
```